# Can a verb and an adjective be linked by the word "and"?

Tags: tenses, sentence

So I'm having a sentence:

> He was active and played with his friends all day

I wonder whether it is correct to use this sentence, because readers may be confused and think that the word "played" used in this case is also in passive voice.

Comment: While I myself wouldn't be confused by the sentence and totally understand `played` is a verb that followed `He` instead of `was`, I am interested in a proper explanation.

Comment: It's a perfectly normal sentence. The _and_ is joining two verb phrases: _was active_ and _played with friends_. This is what happens when you do Conjunction Reduction on _He was active **today** and **he** played with friends today_. Conjunction Reduction will delete the repeated boldface material.

Answer (score 2):

No one will be confused. It's clear that the coordination is of verb phrases as *played* in the passive would not allow *with his friends* to follow it. In fact, the sentence sounds awkward if we force a passive reading:

*He was active and played with all day.*

A verb and an adjective can be linked - enter into a coordination - by *and* if they have similar functions in a sentence:

*He's **known** to have a gun and **likely** to use it*.

*This process is **perfectly natural** and **to be welcomed***.

Answer (score 0):

This very construction, that is where an ellipsis of the suject is found in the second conjunct - is found in the literature often enough and so it must be correct.

[Tater and the Giant Indian - Big Adam - 2011 -](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZWZTAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&dq=%22he+was+active+and%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieq6KSlMroAhWG3OAKHd3rAtgQ6AEIwwEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20active%20and%22&f=false): […] things like vote or play sports or be in Jamboree, unless he was active and went through pledge week.

[Selected Short Stories, D. H. Lawrence - 2012 -](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lKnCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&dq=%22he+was+active+and%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieq6KSlMroAhWG3OAKHd3rAtgQ6AEIggIwFQ#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20active%20and%22&f=false):
By nature he was active, and had many friends.

[The history of England from the invasion of Julius Cesar to ... - Page 385
David Hume - 1810 -](https://books.google.fr/books?id=NiFr3GUuZEQC&pg=PA385&dq=%22he+was+active+and%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieq6KSlMroAhWG3OAKHd3rAtgQ6AEIgQMwIQ#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20active%20and%22&f=false)
In the former part of his life, when he was active and lived in the world, and was probably best known,

[The North West Passage - Page 137 Roald Amundsen, ‎Godfred Hansen - 2014 -](https://books.google.fr/books?id=d18HAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&dq=%22he+was+active+and%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieq6KSlMroAhWG3OAKHd3rAtgQ6AEI-AQwOA#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20active%20and%22&f=false): ‎
In spite of his age he was active and had great stamina;

Comment: Why analyse the sentence as having an ellipsis of the subject? May not two predicates be conjoined?

Comment: @RosieF I am not aware of the various points of view on that question and it seems on first consideration that conjoined predicates are a legitimate possibility. However, from the point of view of the clause structure of the sentence, we have two verbs, therefore two clauses, and they must be independent; this means that they can stand on their own and in order for that to be possible their verbs must have a subject; from that perspective, then, the subject must be introduced and doing so is recognizing it as elliptical in the coordinated sentence. (1/2)

Comment: @RosieF Maybe the two approaches are alternatives that are not mutually exclusive.Another possibility would be the necessity to change the all emcompassing theory of clause structures and consider conjoined predicates as not taken into account by it. I have no definite opinion on this and I do not find any articles discussing it (2/2).